# Drupal 8 Organic Groups Alternative?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules

We have been using Organic Groups on a Drupal 6 system for a few years now.  I see that OG is available on Drupal 7, but no mention of it on Drupal 8.  Is there any module or process for achieving subsites on Drupal 8 much like OG?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be able in D8 as a core functionnality , D8 still in dev ... it's recommanded to use D7 for development today

Comment: We're more in the planning stage right now, so we're not set on D7 or D8 right now.  That being said, I haven't seen anything about OG being in core unless it's been renamed to something else.

Comment: OG8 is being actively ported in https://github.com/amitaibu/og

Answer (score 5):

If you're still looking: [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) just had its first Drupal 8 release.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dev version of og on git : https://github.com/Gizra/og/tree/8.x-1.x

Comment: It's been a year since it has been touched.

Answer (score 1):

Took quite a bit of searching, but it looks like this is the most active port: https://github.com/amitaibu/og

Comment: This is indeed where the porting to D8 is happening. There will be a more public announcement, once things start to get more solid :)

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal 8 port of OG is being tracked at https://www.drupal.org/node/2591017

There's not much code yet, but there are several people interested in porting it and at least one able to work on it as part of their day job.